# Pdf Writer for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, rubygems

Does anyone know of a PDF writer that is easy and works well with Rails 3? If so can someone point me to it and instructs on how to configure it to work with Rails 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are mainly two ways to do a pdf in Rails.

Either you build it from scratch, or use something to generate pdf from html. second one is easier but might not be sufficient if what you're trying to put inside a pdf is more complex.

If you want total control over your pdf, you have to build it from scratch. For that, use a combination between [prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn) and [prawnto](https://github.com/thorny-sun/prawnto).

For the second option, which is easier, you can use [PDFKit](https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit), which uses wkhtmltopdf to generate pdf straight from a html page. I recommend starting with this one and see if it suits your purposes; then, if you think you need more control and this isn't enough, use prawn.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you that, like me some times ago, arrived here looking for the way to make PDF::Writer working in a rails 3 application, perhaps migrating an existing Rails 2.x application, I finally achieved pdf-writer, version 1.1.8, to work in a rails 3.2 application.

In **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'pdf-writer'
```

I have this in config/initializers/pdfwriter_template.rb

```
module ActionView
  module Template::Handlers
    class PDFWriter
      def call(template)
        require_engine 
        "pdf = ::PDF::Writer.new( :paper => 'A4' );" +
        "pdf.compressed = true if Rails.env.to_s == 'production';" +
        template.source + 
        ";pdf.render"
      end

      protected
      def require_engine
        @required ||= begin
          require 'pdf/writer'
          require 'pdf/simpletable'

          true
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_view) do
  ActionView::Template.register_template_handler :rpdf, ActionView::Template::Handlers::PDFWriter.new 
end
```

then in a controller action I can write something like:

```
def pdf_test
  @record = Record.find(params[:id])

  fileout = render_to_string :layout=>false
  send_data(fileout, :type => "application/pdf", :filename => 'test_record.pdf')
end
```

having a template file **pdf_test.rpdf**:

```
pdf.text "Hello from record number #{@record.number}!!"
```

**!!!!!BEWARE: this is not the current best-practice way to render PDF in Rails!!!!!! Use PDFKit or Prawn instead !!!!!**